# Check your internet connection

Tags: installation, software-center

When I'm trying to install synaptics driver for touchpad, I'm getting the error of:

```
Check you internet connection:
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nepomuk-core/nepomuk-core-data_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nepomuk-core/libnepomukcore4abi1_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nepomuk-core/libnepomuksync4_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nepomuk-core/nepomuk-core_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kde-runtime/kde-runtime_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kdepim-runtime/kdepim-runtime_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
    Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pykde4/python-kde4_4.9.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80

]
```

I have a similar issue for installing Krusader as well. But the Internet connection is ok for sure.

Your thought?

Comment: Seems like the version you are trying to fetch is no more in the repository. Can you give the command you gave to get this?

Comment: I found it in software-center

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Does installing other packages work?